# When route to a new page get only data from backend when deploy to HEROKU

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, mern

I have a MERN app working fine locally but when I deploy to heroku, when I route to a new page, it only appears data from backend:
[when route to recipes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQqHI.png)
But when I run local, it works fine:
[route to recipes working fine on local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJhxU.jpg)
Here is the link to my MERN app :

```
https://foodrecipegroup3.herokuapp.com/
```

Anyone can help me to find what the problem is?
Here is my code of server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const routesHandler = require('./routes/handler.js');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');
require('dotenv/config');

mongoose.connect(process.env.DB_URI || 'mongodb+srv://HUYDQ184271:huycoihthd123@cluster0.cmcyc.mongodb.net/myFirstDatabase?retryWrites=true&w=majority', {
    useNewUrlParser:true,
    useUnifiedTopology:true,
    useCreateIndex:true
})
.then( () => {
    console.log('DB connected');
})
.catch( (err) => {
    console.log(err);
})

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use('/',routesHandler);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
    //set static folder
    app.use(express.static('frontend/build'));
}
app.get('*',(req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend', 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
})
```

And here is my package.json on root folder

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",

  "scripts": {
    "server": "nodemon index.js",
    "start": "node index.js",
    "build": "cd frontend && npm run build",
    "install-client": "cd frontend && npm install",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run install-client && npm run build",
    "client": "npm run start --prefix frontend",
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  }, 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the Issue is once the app gets deployed to Heroku or any other platform there is no concept of localhost. localhost only exists in your local environment. So you Axios should be sending a request to

```
axios.post('/receipies', receipies);
//instead of

axios.post('http://localhost:5000/receipies', receipies);
```

because everything is running on one port, and Axios will automatically append the route to the URL.

What I mean by that is if your Heroku app is running on https://foodrecipegroup3.herokuapp.com/(example),

Your URL will be https://foodrecipegroup3.herokuapp.com/recipes once that route is called.

Comment: Is there any way that I can set my server and my frontend run on 2 different ports ?